# Laptop Fan/Heat high when using only Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: fan, heat

I am using I7 Dell laptop. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 along with windows 8. When I use Ubuntu, I feel fan speed is high, which I don't see when using in windows 8.

I installed tlp package but that did not help either.

```
--- TLP 0.4 --------------------------------------------

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    49 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)

I m not sure why Fan speed is not altered.
```

I tried to install Graphics driver from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=13815 but after the hell happened. I lost my unity and all the graphics gone then it took me hours to restore the system with old option.

Do I not have any other option for installing graphics driver or any other remedy like installing Ubuntu 13.10?

Output of `lspci` command is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Chelsea LP [Radeon HD 7730M]
```

Comment: result of lspci cant be that short ..its just two lines , am getting 22 lines..

Comment: maybe you can found sth from this.
the bumblebee project:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: @sushantp606 : I grepped only related to VGA

Comment: have you tried mesa??

Answer (score 1):

Most of times it could be about your graphic card gets warm and because your graphic card is integrated into your cpu the system thinks that cpu gets warm

install `mesa-utils` and `mesa-utils-extras` and reboot  , for installing use the following command-

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
```

it will work for Intel Graphic Cards

If you are having NVIDIA graphic card then use bumblebee because mesa and NVIDIA will conflict with each other for sure.. to install bumblebee use-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/testing
```

then for 12.04 and 13.04 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

otherwise  for 13.10 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generi
```

( for newcomes: the `$` before this command is just an indicator that tells this command should be entered in a standard user command shell. if you want to use it just press `<ctrl>+<alt>+<t>` and copy-paste without this dollar mark )

If that doesnt work, try to

1. `Cleaning your laptop`- As might be its because of just that, stopping fan from running  properly.
2. `Update bios` - After updating it can perform good operations like increasing compatibility .That solved my issue.
3. `Update Kernel`

hope the very first suggestion will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have an Intel CPU with integrated GPU and a discrete NVidia GPU. In Windows graphics driver optimizes the usage of GPU switching between NVidia and Intel GPUs depending on the load.

If this is the case, [install `bumblebee`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Advanced_Setups) package to disable by default NVidia card. On my laptop this saves some battery and decreases fan noise with system temperature